# Actionscript 3, file changes after executing printjob

Tags: flash, actionscript, printing, sprite, stage

I have a button, the related function to this button has the job of printing some parts of the stage. the problem is, after it prints, that specific part appears on top of the stage as an image. I have already used removechild to remove the sprite from the stage but I think the problem is somewhere else.
I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

```
var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
var options:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions();
options.printAsBitmap = false;

printJob.start();
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
bitmapData.draw(stage);
var bitmapDataA:BitmapData = new BitmapData(700,460);
bitmapDataA.copyPixels(bitmapData, new Rectangle(0, 270, 700, 800), new Point(0, 0));

//convert bitmapdata to bitmap to sprite
var screenShot:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapDataA);
addChild(screenShot);
var axSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
axSprite = (bitmapToSprite(screenShot));

//========== printjob bug fix - prevent blank pages: ==========
axSprite.x = 2000;//keep it hidden to the side of the stage
//axSprite.y = 2000;
stage.addChild(axSprite);
//add to stage - prevents blank pages;
//=============================================================

var myScale:Number;
myScale = Math.min(printJob.pageWidth/axSprite.width, printJob.pageHeight/axSprite.height);
axSprite.scaleX = axSprite.scaleY = myScale;
var printArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0, printJob.pageWidth/myScale, printJob.pageHeight/myScale);

printJob.addPage(axSprite, printArea, options);
printJob.send();


stage.removeChild(axSprite);
axSprite = null;
printJob = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the `screenShot` instance to the `displayList` here:

```
//convert bitmapdata to bitmap to sprite
var screenShot:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapDataA);
addChild(screenShot);
var axSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
axSprite = (bitmapToSprite(screenShot));
```

I'm not sure why you would need do this but, if you do, just make sure you remove it again later:

```
stage.removeChild(axSprite);
removeChild(screenShot);
axSprite = null;
printJob = null;
```